# Target input field in document and set & remove a class name if input field has any value

Tags: arrays

I have a bunch of input fields into which I'd like to set a `someClass` name only in condition if an input field has some value. Remove `someClass` name if it doesn't.

I'm currently studying manipulating forms and forms fields using JavaScript and this is the code I'm working on.

```
// Add a class to an element, without removing/affecting existing values

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  // Set HTML elements collection index?
  var input = inputs[i];

  input.addEventListener('input', function() {

    if (input.value.length > 0 && !input.className.match(/(?:^|\s)someClass(?!\S)/)) {
        console.log("Input has some value");
        input.className += "someClass";
    }

    if (input.value.length == 0) {
        console.log("Input is empty");
        input.className = input.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)someClass(?!\S)/g , '' );
    }

  });
}
```

The current code do what it suppose to do only on last input field. It occurred to me that `var input` is overwritten every time there is a new loop.
So I was thinking to target current element by some conditional statement within the loop. I can't think of anything else (with little knowledge I have about this) except manually assigning some of input's attributes.

Comment: I believe you should be able to use 'this' within the event listener to refer to the element that triggered the event, does that help?

Comment: @SeanBurton, there is quiet a lot to learn about the keyword `this`. Generally I understand `this` in this situation but I must go from the root to understand `this` JS keyword. ( Thanks for your comment Sean! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that each input event listener is updating w/e element the variable `input` is representing *at the time the event is fired*, and is therefore only updating that element.

So the timeline goes like this:

1. Add event listener to input 1 | `input` = input1
2. Add Event Listener to input 2 | `input` = input2
3. Add event listener to input 3 | `input` = input3

All 3 event listeners are going to change the element held by variable `input`, which at this time is only input3.

4. User clicks inside input and types
5. var `input` which is input3 gets updated

As Sean pointed out, you need each eventListener function to update the specific element that fired that event. Here you have 3 options:

1. Use this `this` keyword
   https://jsfiddle.net/5gbnykme/1/
2. Use `event.target` as reference 
   https://jsfiddle.net/5gbnykme/2/
3. Use a wrapper function to scope your variable locally
   https://jsfiddle.net/5gbnykme/3/

**TL;DR** Make sure the element called in your event listener is the element that triggered the event.

Comment: TJ, timeline is really good helper here because it helps you understand execution. That is really what helps to learn. Anyway, thanks for all three options. I'll go through them properly one more time but I think the third one seems to be quiet nice as you refer to input fields by variables in array function.